# Appropriate layout for an address form

Tags: forms, addresses

I've read a number of the questions both on here and elsewhere suggesting to avoid a two-column layout, lest you have to zig-zag with your eyes while filling it out and risk missing fields.

I'm working on a basic address form as part of a multi-step, and have opted for a single column, multiline layout. The challenge so far has been appropriate sizing of the fields while maintaining a fairly intuitive layout. What I have so far is this:

[image]

I'm not entirely satisfied with it, as I feel the Country drop-down is kind of "floating" about by itself, but the alternative was to simply have all fields exactly the same length:
[image]

Is one necessarily better than the other? Or is the form simple enough that really, it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1):

**The fist one is better**

The three fields City, State, Postcode should be close together. In the second one it is not clear if the postcode has anything to do with the country.

Answer (score 1):

Address form design differs for the country you are designing it for which will influence how you arrange the fields.

Fields arrangement:
In certain countries like the UK and Japan, the postcode will be the first in the list. User will key in postcode and it will autofill other address fields.

Width:
Each field has different width. Street address is normally the longest so do provide enough width.

You can study on the shipping/ billing address section at e-commerce.